# how to put single quote in Evaluate_Aggr?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, business-intelligence, obiee

I have the following code in OBIEE:

```
EVALUATE_AGGR( 'LTRIM(RTRIM(SYS.STRAGG(DISTINCT %1|| '', ''), '', '') , '', '')' as varchar(2000), 
EVALUATE('GetValue(%1,''SELECT MAX(I1.ITEM_NUMBER)INTO :strValue                             
FROM MV_BOM B1, MV_ITEM I1                                                  
WHERE  BOM_PARENT_ITEM_NUMBER = XXXX AND                                                         
B1.BOM_CHILD_ITEM_SUBCLASS = "Stic" AND                                                
B1.BOM_PARENT_ITEM_SUBCLASS = "Product" AND                      
B1.BOM_CHILD_ITEM_NUMBER=I1.ITEM_NUMBER AND                     
NOT I1.ITEM_NUMBER LIKE "4.YY%" AND             
NOT I1.ITEM_NUMBER LIKE "4.WW%" AND           
NOT I1.ITEM_NUMBER LIKE "DXXXT.%" AND                  
I1.ITEM_LATEST_FLAG="Latest Revision" '' )' AS VARCHAR(2000),  "Product value" ))
```

for which I am getting a syntax error: Near     getvalue(%1,'  the single quote
I tried to play with the quote but still not working. Any help?

Comment: Which syntax error do you get, with the exact code you've posted?

Comment: Hi Alex, Near <getvalue(%1,'>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't add single quotes like that. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, other than use evaluate as a way to run your own SQL which is not what it is designed for.